# Disassociated/deleted user's posts still showing up on Careers profile

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs, deleted-accounts

I was looking at [a user's Stack Overflow Careers portfolio](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/h2co3), which had multiple answers which seems to have been disassociated (I think after the account was deleted?).

For example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964371/how-to-detect-first-time-app-launch-on-an-iphone/9964400#9964400) was shown up as one of the top answers posted, despite the post having being disasociated.

If that's the case, shouldn't they be removed from the portfolio?

Comment: Also, they requested deletion [in February](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221102/what-happened-to-the-moderator-election-candidate-h2co3/221106#221106), but [that hasn't fully happened yet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3565300/h2co3).

Comment: Oh, that's a different account. Probably something that was created automatically again when he logged in to some of the other sites?

Answer (score 2):

We don't touch a users profile as it is up to the sole discretion of the user to modify their profile. Also, in my opinion, just because he deleted his account, doesn't make his contribution to SO any less his achievement and should still be valid for use on his CV.

Now, if he deletes the questions from his profile, I'm not sure if he would be able to re-add it. But that's another issue.